# Do mosquito repellent sprays work on all insects?

Tags: zoology, entomology

I would like to know the mode of action of mosquito repellent aerosols. Are these specific to mosquito or are other insects affected too?

Comment: Are you specifically interested in the aerosols. The sprays are sometimes insecticidal as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common active ingredient in insect repellents is *N*,*N*-diethyl-3-methylbenzamide (other name: *N*,*N*-diethyl-*m*-toluamide; abbreviated DEET). It provides protection against mosquitoes and many other insects. After various interesting hypotheses, it is currently assumed that mosquitoes simply smell DEET directly and avoid it.[[1]](http://www.pnas.org/content/early/2008/08/19/0805312105)

Comment: Could you add some references to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Citronella oil is also used as an insect repellent and is seems effective on mosquitoes[[1](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1748-5967.2005.tb00146.x/abstract;jsessionid=48028622D4EDE52827A4E29ACC82E9CA.f04t03)] and head lice[[2](http://www.ima.org.il/IMAJ/ViewArticle.aspx?year=2004&month=12&page=75603)] as well. Though I was not able to find information on the mode of action, just the effectiveness of citronella.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEET) also says DEET is effective for fleas, ticks, and chiggers (though this lacks a references). Anecdotally, I know the Off brand of repellent is useful when the dogs get fleas to avoid getting all bitten up (Off contains DEET I believe).